# Error 404 in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have a project divided into different modules.

I have copy pasted one module into my protected/modules folder.

When I try to open the it in browser it shows me error 404:unable to process the request.

But, I am able to open the modules on which I have worked on. The problem is with the ones that I have copy pasted only.

Comment: can you check the .htaccess and compare with working modules. How you tried to access the modules.

Comment: Have you edited your `config.php` to include the module?

Comment: you have to copy Controller file Model file and view files into your protected folder

Comment: Yes..I have included the module in config.php, but no use

Comment: I have copied model, controller and view into my module folder, it isn't working

Answer (score 1):

1- add in config.php:

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'application.modules.*',
    ),
```

2- chack apache **mod_rewrite**

3- chacke `apache/site-aviable/default` and set `AllowOverride` to `All`